# Fade animation for SKLabelNode changing text

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, fade, sklabelnode

Okay so I have implemented a simple SKLabelNode with some text.

I want to add a fade animation when I change the text.

I know there is an easy way to do it with UILabels but I cant figure out how to do it with SKLabels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run an SKAction (fade) on it

```
let label = SKLabelNode(...
label.fontSize = ...
label.fontColor = ...
label.position = ...
addChild(label)

let fadeAction = SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0.5, duration: 1)
label.runAction(fadeAction)
```

Hope that helps